# How can I check RAM of my laptop?

Tags: 16.04, graphics

RAM: 2143MiB / 3798MiB

What does this means ?
I cannot even know about my laptop's RAM

Comment: Where did you see this? Why is this tagged [tag:graphics]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line you can use:

```
free
```

to check your (free/available) RAM. Also do:

```
man free
```

Comment: you can also run `free -g` and it will show you in GiB  or `free -m` will be MiB... you will look at `total` `used` and `available` just a note tho that it may be just slightly less  than you are are supposed to have .. thats normal .. like yours says 3798MiB .. that would be 4GB ram

Answer (score 1):

You could as well use either `top` (preinstalled) or `htop` to monitor your memory usage.

It adds some details `free` doesn't (context to running processes)